# cant open any cshtml file after updating visual studio 2013 to update 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

After updating Visual Studio 2013 to update 4 I can't open any CSHTML file in any new asp.net MVC project.

Here is the error I'm getting when trying to open any CSHTML file:

```
The document cannot be opened. It has been renamed, deleted or moved.
```

ps:
I can open cshtml files with right click and open-with > XML Editor. My Issue is with open cshtml files with "HTML Editor (Default)".
Also i can open cshtml files from older projects, the issue is just for new projects.

How to fix this?

Comment: try removing the project and adding it back to the solution.

Comment: Do you use specific VS extensions?

Comment: like web essentials do u mean ?

Comment: No, like Xamarin: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26850

Comment: I checked , i dont have Xamarin.